# How to update a view in particular position in recycler view?

Tags: android

I have a recycler view in that i have many rows.each row has many items.onclick of one item in a row,I need to change the view of that row based on particular position.As,I am new to android,can anyone help me.

Comment: You should do your own research before asking question. I'm sure google is full of tutorials on this topic

Comment: You can use the `notifyItemChanged(int position)`.

Comment: post the code of your model class and listadapter

Comment: You need to update, remove, insert, or delete an item in the dataset of the adapter and the call the according `notify..` method i.e. (`notifyItemChanged`)

Comment: you can use view type for different view for same recyclerview and then you can notifyItemChanged for particulate position,. for example you can check loadmore recycler view wich has two view Types.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your data in an `ArrayList` update the data of that particular position in `ArrayList` and call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` and in your bindViewHolder handle what you have to show by the value changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: post the code relevant to your answer , only providing method name is not a sufficient answer even it could be a comment